# String ^ MyString = gcnew String("abcd");

Tags: pointers, reference, c++-cli, dereference

I was reading the c++'s [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx) syntax on MSDN:

```
// for_each_string1.cpp  
// compile with: /ZW  
#include <stdio.h>  
using namespace Platform;  

ref struct MyClass {  
   property String^ MyStringProperty;  
};  

int main() {  
   String^ MyString = ref new String("abcd");  

   for each ( char c in MyString )  
      wprintf("%c", c);  

   wprintf("/n");  

   MyClass^ x = ref new MyClass();  
   x->MyStringProperty = "Testing";  

   for each( char c in x->MyStringProperty )  
      wprintf("%c", c);  
}
```

I tried to find what the "^" means on google but I couldn't find anything (or my query wasn't correct)

What does it mean? Is it as a "*"? Is it as a "&"?

This syntax also applies to C#. Do they mean the same thing in both languages?

Piece of C# [code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arich/2004/09/08/the-c-for-each-syntax/):

```
using namespace System;

int main(){
  array<int>^ arr = gcnew array<int>{0,1,2,5,7,8,11};
  int even=0, odd=0;

  for each (int i in arr) {
    if (i%2 == 0)  
      even++;      
    else 
      odd++;         
  }

  Console::WriteLine(“Found {0} Odd Numbers, and {1} Even Numbers.”,
    odd, even);
}
```

Comment: This isn't C++, it's Microsoft's proprietary language, C++/CLI.

Comment: This is not C++, it's C++/CLI.

Comment: DirectX also uses this. What does it mean anyways?

Comment: Removed the C# tag since there is no C# in this question.

Comment: Both of your snippets are in C++/CLI

Comment: Saw the "WriteLine" and immediately associated with C#. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The "^" denotes a managed reference, which is used for managed types. It's like a pointer, but for managed types. The syntax doesn't exist in C#. In C#, the equivalent is just a variable of a reference type (as opposed to a value type), or a boxed value type.

As others have said, this is C++/CLI syntax which means you have to compile with the /clr option. C++/CLI is basically C++ with features of C# (or more generally, .NET).

Comment: *C++/CLI is basically C++...*. I honestly doubt that. Your answer is a good one with the exception of that last sentence.

Comment: @RawN Why not? C++/CLI is a superset of C++, with features added to interface with .NET. The C++ subset works identically to how it works in unmanaged C++.

Comment: *C++/CLI should be thought of as a language of its own (with a new set of keywords, for example), instead of the C++ superset-oriented Managed C++* [as explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Syntax_changes).

Comment: @RawN it's a language on its own but it's still technically a superset of C++03.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019 hope this link can help you.
btw,^ is a special character and  ignored by google search engine so you can not search that.